# Ember can't find watchman, but watchman seems to be installed properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ember.js, watchman

Yet another ember + watchman question.

`ember -v` yields

```
version: 1.13.8
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
node: 0.12.7
npm: 2.13.4
os: linux x64
```

However, `watchman -v` yields

```
3.8.0
```

Also, for the record, here's my `/etc/*-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

I followed my usual way of setting up ember (and watchman), which usually works. From what I remember, ember works with watchman version 3.8.0, though I might be wrong.

Comment: 3.8 is the master branch.  Can you checkout the v3.7.0 tag for watchman and build+install that just to rule out any of the unreleased changes?

Comment: The 3.7 release actually did the job.

Comment: would you mind opening an issue on our github tracker and include your watchman logs? I'd like to understand more about what happened before we release 3.8.  Thanks!